# FIXED!!! How can I run an ffmpeg command in spyder which converts movies located on an external harddrive?

Tags: command, spyder, os.system

**Error was something completely else. ffmpeg works just fine when giving the complete paths, the problem was a folder called freek data instead of freek_data
rookie mistake :O**

This is the command I use:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec msmpeg4v2 -acodec copy output.avi
```

It works, I've tested it.
That is, it works when accessing a file on the local harddrive 'C:'.
However, now my file is on an external harddrive: 'D:'.
In a **command terminal**, the ffmpeg line **still works** by subsequently typing:

```
D:
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec msmpeg4v2 -acodec copy output.avi
```

However, the module **os.system** which I use in spyder **can't do that**.
How I use os.system:

```
command = f'ffmpeg -i {input} -vcodec msmpeg4v2 -acodec copy {input[:-4]}_com.avi'
os.system('D:') #if file on D:, otherwise leave this line out
os.system(command)
```

The os.system however doesn't seem to be able to run subsequent commands *(probably an other term for this, but you may understand what I mean)*.
Can someone give me a fix for how I can acces files on an external harddrive using ffmpeg in a spyder script?

Thannks in advance, Freek

*What I tried:
I tried using os.system and running two command after each other as explained in the desrciption. I looked online into the module subprocess, which I believe has some more functionalities compared to os.system, I however couldn't understand how it works and also don't know if it is capable of solving the problem at hand.*